# How to make a tikz node with differently styled text and line breaks

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, line-breaking

I am trying to create a tikz node with differently styled text. Adding a line break inside a bold text breaks the rendering with:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \tikz@invoke@collected@onpath ...mmand \tikz@temp 
>                                                     \pgf@stop \tikz@node@is@a@...
>   l.14 \testNode{1}{Normal text}{Bold\\text}

This code reproduces the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,arrows,arrows.meta,calc}
\tikzstyle{theTest} = [font=\small, draw, thin, align=flush center, minimum height=1em, node distance=3em]
\newcommand{\testNode}[3]{
\node[theTest] (#1) {
#2\\
\textbf{#3}
};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\testNode{1}{Normal text}{Bold\\text}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit: I am looking for a dynamic approach, where I don't know whether "bold text" has or has not a new line.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\\` must not be inside `\textbf`, because the multi-line feature works similar to a table (`tabular`, `array`).

The formatting `\textbf{bold\\text}` must be applied in both rows:

```
\textbf{bold}\\\textbf{text}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning,
  shapes.multipart,
  shapes.geometric,
  arrows,
  arrows.meta,
  calc
}

\tikzstyle{theTest} = [
  font=\small,
  draw,
  thin,
  align=flush center,
  minimum height=1em,
  node distance=3em,
]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[theTest] (1) {
  Normal text\\
  \textbf{bold text}
};

\node[theTest,below of=1] (2) {
  Normal text\\
  %\textbf{bold\\text}
  \textbf{bold}\\
  \textbf{text}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If the text is provided by a macro with arbitrary contents, then a `\parbox` or environment `minipage` can be used. The following example uses environment `varwidth`, which is able to decrease the width of the overall box, when the lines are shorter than specified:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{theTest} = [
  font=\small,
  draw,
  thin,
  align=flush center,
  minimum height=1em,
  node distance=3em,
]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand\mymacro{Normal text\\\textbf{bold\\text}}

\node[theTest] (1) {%
  \begin{varwidth}{.2\linewidth}% maximum width
    \centering
    \mymacro
  \end{varwidth}%
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with varwidth]

Comment: What if I use this node in a makro and the text "bold text" is provided as a parameter. In this case I cannot extract the \\. Is there a way to support this?

Comment: @Paul See updated answer.

Comment: Now, the boxes cannot be arbitrarily large. This is not my direct intention. However without .2 I got my intended result. Thank you.